# How to save a date into a database using @Html.DisplayFor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Hi guys I am new this place I have been recommended to this site. My problem is i have a application in MVC3 C# in asp.net2010 and this application adds, edits and deletes text from a database and my next step is to create a way in which allows a automated date to be inputted. Currently this is done manually when a user clicks on the link create new and inputs the details he/she has to input the date manually I would like a way in which when the user clicks on link create new the date is automatically there for them so they just press enter.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Posted) I have tried to edit this so it shows this:

<%: Html.TextBox("date", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()) %> /*This code does replace the @Html.EditorFor link above and does not save the date and just shows it a text box"*/.

@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MyDateTime.ToLongDateString())

@{var val = item.MyDateTime.ToLongDateString();
  Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => val);
}
```

None of these methods work or properly can you please help me thank you

I have been at this for ages looked everywhere on Google and yahoo had no luck I know it has something to do with this @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Posted) as when i click on create new it allows the user to input a date manually.

Thank you for your time Please if you require more information on code Ect... just ask me

Answer (score 1):

You could decorate your view model `Posted` property with the [`[DisplayFormat]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) attribute, like so:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
public DateTime Posted { get; set; }
```

Now, when in your view you use:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Posted)
```

you will get the desired format. As far as only displaying the date without rendering an input field is concerned you could use the DisplayFor helper and it will still respect the desired format that you have defined on your view model:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Posted)
```

Comment: Where shall i put the first line of code you have provided? does it belong in the Models/AccountModels.cs file or the controller I am a little confused with this? thank you

Comment: @user1128756, it should belong to your model class. Your view is strongly typed to some model since you are using the Html.EditorFor helper.

Comment: Yes that is correct but this model class I can not find it does it have the following at the end bare in mine my model is called "News" so its the class any one of these files: Model1.context.tt, Model1.tt, NewsModel.edmx Because this is first time I am hearing about a class which I am not familiar with. Thank you for your help

Comment: @user1128756, you should not pass your autogenerated domain models to your views. You should use view models. View models are classes that you define and which contain the specific properties and formatting your view needs. So in this view you need to format the date in a given format. So you define a view model with a `Posted` property that you decorate as shown in my answer and then you have your controller action query the data access layer to fetch a domain model that will be converted to a view model and passed to the view for displaying.

Comment: So the first line of code goes in to the controller? I am not talking about passing autogenerated domain models to my views. You told me that the code belongs to my model class. I asked are any of these my model class "Model1.context.tt, Model1.tt, NewsModel.edmx" since these files are in my models folder. I understand what you are saying that "@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Posted)" this should go in view but where does the code you wrote at the very first sentence go to thank you so much for you kind help

Comment: If i put this code in my controller " [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
        public DateTime Posted { get; set; }" it gives the error 



Error 1 The type or namespace name 'DisplayFormatAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) so it clearly does not belong in the controller. This is what am stuck at where does this code go? Thank you for you kind help sir

Comment: Add `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;` to the top of your page to bring the namespace into which this attribute is declared into scope.

Comment: I shall try this thank you and will report of any error but you still haven't told me if am putting the code [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
public DateTime Posted { get; set; } in to the controller? or some model? But I will assume that you mean controller and go along with your code Thank you for the assistance and will report back once i have made the change.

Comment: All it does is grays out the text box so nothing can inputted this not correct If i wanted to do this i would have removed the editor box totally this defies the purpose of having a time and date my question was and still is how to enter a automated date that is always there which i press enter this is the current date that i want inputting not the date that is already there you have read my question out of context. But thank you for the code but this is not what I wanted.

Comment: I want to use the command DateTime.Now so the @Html.EditorFor picks up the current date so when I add a new item to the database it know that the date is current Hench the word automated (as in current, automatic)